# Postgresql Tracing

Tags: postgresql, trace

Is query tracing on Postgresql possible?  I am using 9.0 on windows with OLEDB interface.

Also, I need it to be in real-time, not buffered like it is by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean tracing the statements on the server side?

In that case, change the parameter log_min_duration to 0 in postgresql.conf.

You don't need to restart the server, just reload the configuration (pg_ctl reload)

Comment: i found the config options and now I have the log - however - it is lagging behind i.e. isn't flushed regularly.  is there any option to enable real-time log flushing so I can tail it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to control this

Comment: On Second thought, you might be able to get something out of pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity, but it doesn't keep a history of statements, only the currently executed ones